# STM32L0 GPIO EXTI interrupt not triggering

Tags: stm32, arm, mbed

I'm working with an STM32L073RZ on a custom board. The board is in STOP mode and I have a pin (PB_5) configured as a rising edge interrupt. I'm using ARM Mbed OS 5.12.0 but primarily working with the HAL API.

Here's the code I have so far; `main.h` is just a bunch of pin definitions. I'm expecting pin PB_4 to toggle every time there is a rising edge on PB_5.

```
#include "main.h"

void SystemClock_Config() {
    __HAL_RCC_PLL_DISABLE();

    __HAL_RCC_MSI_ENABLE();

    __HAL_RCC_MSI_RANGE_CONFIG(RCC_MSIRANGE_5);
    __HAL_RCC_MSI_CALIBRATIONVALUE_ADJUST(0x00);

    RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_MSI;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

    HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_1);

    __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE3);
}

void Pwr_Config() {
    __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();

    __HAL_RCC_WAKEUPSTOP_CLK_CONFIG(RCC_STOP_WAKEUPCLOCK_MSI);
}

void GPIO_Config() {
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_All;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;

    __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOE_CLK_ENABLE();  

    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct); 
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStruct);
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOH, &GPIO_InitStruct);
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOE, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_DISABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_DISABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_DISABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_DISABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOE_CLK_DISABLE();

    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_5;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_RISING;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLDOWN;

    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

    __HAL_GPIO_EXTI_CLEAR_IT(GPIO_PIN_5);
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI4_15_IRQn, 0, 1);
    HAL_NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(EXTI4_15_IRQn);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI4_15_IRQn);

    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_4;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;

    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);  
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
}

void StopMode_Enter() {
    HAL_PWREx_EnableUltraLowPower();

    __HAL_PWR_CLEAR_FLAG(PWR_FLAG_WU);

    HAL_PWR_EnterSTOPMode(PWR_LOWPOWERREGULATOR_ON, PWR_STOPENTRY_WFI);
}

void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(uint16_t GPIO_Pin) {
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_4);
}

int main()
{
    while(true) {
        load_cell_en = 0;
        modem_reg_en = 0;

        SystemClock_Config();
        Pwr_Config();
        GPIO_Config();

        StopMode_Enter();
    }  
}
```

As far as I'm aware, simply overriding the `HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback` function is the way to handle an interrupt, but the pin never toggles. What am I missing here?

In STOP mode I believe I should simply place the CPU into STOP mode once and do any processing in an ISR as opposed to, for example, a state machine?

Thanks.

Comment: Stop mode is more complicated. Wakeup sources are limited, and ridden with errata. I'm not familiar with the L0, but this does not look correct. Search for examples and check erratasheets.

Comment: @Jeroen3 Thanks for the comment. As far as I'm aware I should be able to wake from an interrupt on any EXTI line and I'm not aware of any errata that are applicable to my situation (though I may have missed something..). It appears that the CPU wakes as any code after entry to STOP mode gets executed upon a rising edge applied to the specificed pin, but the callback function never appears to be executed.

Comment: @amitchone have you ever found the reason why the CPU wakes up from STOP as expected from an edge on that line, but then the corresponding EXTI callback is not called? However, the callback works perfectly while the CPU is not in STOP mode. Thanks!